# Assembly of constructor for virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, assembly, constructor, x86, virtual-inheritance

Here's a simple inheritance usinig a virtual base class (code [available](https://godbolt.org/z/4VC2ph) on Compiler Explorer).

```
class B {
public:
    int i = 1;
};

class D : virtual public B {
public:
    int j = 2;
};

void Assign(B *b) {
    b->i = 2;
}

int main() {
    B *b = new D();
    Assign(b);
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly listing of the `main()` function looks like this:

```
09  main: # @main
10    push rbp
11    mov rbp, rsp
12    sub rsp, 32
13    mov eax, 16
14    mov edi, eax
15    mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
16    call operator new(unsigned long)
17    xor esi, esi
18    mov ecx, 16
19    mov edx, ecx
20    mov rdi, rax
21    mov qword ptr [rbp - 24], rax # 8-byte Spill
22    call memset
23    mov rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 24] # 8-byte Reload
24    call D::D() [complete object constructor]
25    xor ecx, ecx
26    mov eax, ecx

27    mov rdx, qword ptr [rbp - 24] # 8-byte Reload
28    cmp rdx, 0
29    mov qword ptr [rbp - 32], rax # 8-byte Spill
30    je .LBB1_2
31    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 24] # 8-byte Reload
32    mov rcx, qword ptr [rax]
33    mov rcx, qword ptr [rcx - 24]
34    add rax, rcx
35    mov qword ptr [rbp - 32], rax # 8-byte Spill
36  .LBB1_2:
37    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 32] # 8-byte Reload
38    mov qword ptr [rbp - 16], rax

39    mov rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 16]
40    call Assign(B*)
41    xor eax, eax
42    add rsp, 32
43    pop rbp
44    ret
```

What is the effect of line 27-38 of the assembly?

What is the value of `rax` in line 29?

Why is there a branch statement?

Comment: Can you still get similar code with `-Og`?  `-O0` debug mode is a mess.  IDK if gcc would be doing speculative devirtualization at `-O0` but it might be.

Comment: Hint: pay attention to the "vtable for D" symbol, first member!

Comment: @curiousguy What do you mean?

Comment: @chaosink The 1st field of the vtable of the derived class contains the information the compiler needs here: "`vtable for D:
        .quad   12`" It means that base is at offset +12 from the `D` base class (lax) subobject in the most derived object `D`. (It's easier to speak in term of lax subobject where a derived object is a subobject of itself.) Be careful the vptr doesn't point to the beginning of the vtable! By historical convention `vptr[0]` is the first virtual function (if there is any, or the one of the end of the virtual function array). The offsets are at negative offsets WRT vptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of lines 27-38 is to convert a `D *` to a `B *`.  Because `B` is a virtual base class, it can have a variable offset from the start of `D`.  Those 12 lines calculate where the `B` object is, in an unoptimized way.

The value of `eax` on line 29 is 0 (see lines 25-26).

The branch statement on line 30 is the result of a NULL pointer check.  If the pointer to `D` is NULL, the conversion to a `B *` will also be NULL and the extra code to determine the correct offset is not wanted in that case.

Comment: It makes it easier to see it if you split out the `D*` to `B*` conversion into a separate statement.  And even easier if you put it into a *function* so you can enable optimization without removing it.  https://godbolt.org/z/4-deOJ